# what operators should be methods , friends, and non-member function?

Tags: c++, class, methods, friend, non-member-functions

I have searched for a specific answer for my question and i couldn't find one , so here is my question:

1. I know that if we have `operator+` and `operator+=` `+=` should be a method and `+` a non-member function
   but what if we didn't have `operator+=` , should `operator+` be `friend` then ?
2. I also know that symmetrical operators should be 'non-members' and 'friends' if needed , and I can see how `==` `!=` are symmetrical operators, but what about `<` , `>` , `>=` , `<=` are they symmetric? and why ?  I mean `A<B` is not the same as `B<A` , so are they symmetric? should they be declared as non-members? friends?

Comment: Since C++20, there is [`<=>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_comparisons) to replace most of them.

Comment: @Jarod42 we use C++11 in the course I learn in university